# delete commits permanently from fossil repository

Tags: fossil

As the `timeline` below shows, I forgot to `add` prior to `commit` and produced two checkins ...4a and ...3d. Then checked out ...97, repeated the change and committed with `--allow-fork` ...85. How can I get rid of checkins ...4a and ...3d?

```
user@PC:~/blinky$ fossil timeline
=== 2019-11-18 ===
17:00:08 [199f536985] *CURRENT* Move LED functions to BSP (user: user tags: trunk)
16:45:55 [b44070073d] Move LED functions to BSP (user: user tags: trunk)
16:44:03 [8e1bd6364a] Move LED functions to BSP (user: user tags: trunk)
15:35:02 [b9c7685997] *FORK* blah blah
15:16:11 [d1629aa3fa] Initial commit (user: user tags: trunk)
14:39:08 [7fe2388931] initial empty check-in (user: user tags: trunk)
+++ no more data (6) +++
```

**PS**: stumbled upon [Rebase Considered Harmful](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/rebaseharm.md), explaining the downside of "cleaner history".

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32119071/) helped: `fossil purge checkins b44070073d 8e1bd6364a`

Comment: Just a note: You need to be careful as you cannot purge specific check-ins without also purging all descendants.  Although you could with some extra work, like change the tag to some other, then re-parent, and then purge.  But extra caution is needed (and always try it on a backup).